# Display Images in AngularJS Modal inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-app lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    ul>li, a{cursor: pointer;}
    </style>
    <title>get some data from the database</title>



</head>
<body ng-controller="delayController">
<div ng-controller="customersCrtl">
<div class="container">
<br/>
<blockquote><h4 dir="rtl" align="center"><a href="index.html">test</a></h4></blockquote>
<br/>
    <div dir="rtl" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">num of items per page:
            <select ng-model="entryLimit" class="form-control">
                <option>5</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>20</option>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>100</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">search:
            <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="enter what you are looking for" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div dir="rtl" class="col-md-4">
            <h5>showing {{ filtered.length }} out of {{ totalItems}} items</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div dir="rtl" align="center" class="alert alert-info" ng-show="loading"><img ng-src="images/131.gif"/><h2>loading details...</h2>

<div ng-controller="customersCrtl" class="container">

  <progressbar class="progress-striped active" type="info" animate="true" max="100" value="progressBar.progress"><b>{{progressBar.progress}}%</b></progressbar>

</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" dir="rtl">
        <div dir="rtl" class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
            <table align="right" dir="rtl" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <th>item name&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('name');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th>item price&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('price');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.price}}&nbsp;
                    <a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{data.imagedata}}" target="_blank"><img src="images/binoculars.png" height="12" width="12"></a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div dir="rtl" class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4>לא נמצאו מוצרים.</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
            <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="דף קודם" next-text="דף הבא"></div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-count-to.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','countTo']);
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|http?|file|data):/);
}]);

app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.$emit('LOAD');
    $scope.progressBar = { progress : 0 };
    $http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 50; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
        $scope.$emit('UNLOAD');

    });
    (function progress(){
        if($scope.progressBar.progress < 100){
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.progressBar.progress += 1;
                progress();
            },100);
        }
    })();

    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});

app.controller('delayController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.$on('LOAD',function(){$scope.loading=true});
    $scope.$on('UNLOAD',function(){$scope.loading=false});
    }]);
```

As you can see, at the moment, the image is opened in a new tab/window and it looks a bit off. This is the reason for wanting it to be opened in a modal like window.

Comment: If your modal has its own controller then you can inject the imageData via a service, or if it has a scope nested in a parent scope which already has the imagedata, it can just inherit that data if it is avaialble on that parent scope.

Comment: I actually dont have a modal controller yet as I am not sure how to use it. Do you have an example?

Comment: See my answer below. Note that I am assuming you are using AngularUI bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any controller to the bootstrap modal service as so.
Just create your controller and place your image data on its scope.
Then, pass it to the open call of the modal service.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8TfCPs?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log,$sce) {

  var parentScope = $scope;

  $scope.imgs =[];
  $scope.imgs.push($sce.trustAsUrl("http://dummyimage.com/64X64/000/f00"));
  $scope.imgs.push($sce.trustAsUrl("http://dummyimage.com/64X64/000/0f0"));
  $scope.imgs.push($sce.trustAsUrl("http://dummyimage.com/64X64/000/00f"));

  $scope.open = function () {

    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        backdrop: true,
        windowClass: 'modal',
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.imgs = parentScope.imgs;
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }
    });
};
};
```

Now, as an addendum based on your comments, if you are using image data encoded in base64 you will need to build up the url using $sce.trustAsResourceUrl

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

http://plnkr.co/edit/jRXHL3zSR8rDT1sJJ1tw?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.16" data-semver="1.3.16" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <img ng-src="{{imgUri}}"/>


    <script>
      var app = angular.module("app",[]);

      app.controller("testCtrl",function($scope,$sce){
        var data="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";
        $scope.imgUri = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("data:image/png;base64," + data);
      });

      angular.bootstrap(document,[app.name]);
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your example works well if you specify the image data in the controller. I would like to pass the image url (base64 encoded - coming from the database). I am editing the original post to include both my index.html and the app.js

Comment: Observe the modal controller is nested inside the parent controller. Assuming you have the data available to the parent then it is also available to the child.

Comment: Modified the code to demonstrate one way the nested modal controller can access the images from the outer controller.

Comment: currently, you are pushing a list of images which makes it like a gallery. it needs to pass only one image.

Comment: Pass what you need for your solution. It doesn't matter at all that I put the images in an array.

Comment: Yes. I tested it and you are correct. the thing is, I am trying to pass information to the modal inside an ng-repeat which shows the data. I tried using the script inside of the rows but it looks like the data is not passed into the script. it only works if a manually pass a url.

Comment: how do i just pass the image.data to the img ng-src=

Comment: You will need to trust the data as a resource URL, I will post another example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) Use:

```
<img ng-src="data.imagedata" alt="Description"/>
```

Comment: I dont want to display the image in the table. I want to display it in a new modal window.